# convert utf8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I need to convert a txt file from utf8 to ISO-8859-1
the content of the file is : MOD CNACLD:P=0,PFX=K'12345,ADDR=ALL,RSNAME="1_2"

I tried to convert it with iconv :

> iconv  -f utf8 -t ISO-8859-1   test.txt -o test1.txt

but I'm getting :

> iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0

and when I use ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT, it doesn't show an error , but file -i test1.txt output is :

> text/plain; charset=us-ascii

any support is appreciated

Comment: Well, it looks like the file only contains ASCII characters, so it will be indistinguishable from an ASCII file. Check with a hex editor what that first byte iconv complains about is exactly. Probably a BOM.

Comment: what's iconv? What is the programming context of this question?